# firebase 3 can we sign in after firebase.database().goOffline()?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, offline, firebase-authentication

My react-native App works fine when online, now i'm trying the offline behavior.

I've tried to go offline (firebase.database().goOffline() then switched off wifi and run).

I get the firebase error "auth/network-request-failed" with the following code:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'
config = {
  apiKey:  `${ Config.firebase.apiKey }`,
  authDomain: `${ Config.firebase.authDomain }`,
  databaseURL: `${ Config.firebase.databaseURL }`,
  storageBucket: `${ Config.firebase.storageBucket }`
}

firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
firebase.database().goOffline()
const credentials = Firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)

firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials)
.then((user) => {
  console.log('signin ok', user)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('signin error', error)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing in to Firebase Authentication requires an active network connection. It is not possible to sign in when there is no active network connection.

After all, what would the `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential` compare the email+password to, if it can't access the servers?

Comment: Thx Frank for your answer, now there should be a way to do some kind of authorization offline as Firebase save tokens and data locally if i'm not wrong. Or said in other way, how do we manage the offline mode in react native apps when no network available ?

Comment: There is no way you can authenticate offline and there shouldn't be. However, if you previously logged in and then you go offline, you should still be considered logged in until the network connection resumes. You can test this by logging in and then go offline, refresh your app and notice, onAuthStateChanged still triggers as expected with the offline user and currentUser is populated.

Comment: @bojeil got it, indeed still logged in, just have to change my internal login process & app bootstrapping when online/offline then. thx.